# Add X number of years to a datetime variable SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to add 10 years to the year portion of the date with date stored in the format yyyy-mm-dd for everyone who visited in the year 2010.  Below is the query I want to try but I don't know how to use the rollback function of SQL Server yet. Visityear is varchar datatype.

```
update myTable
set admitdate=dateadd(yyyy,10,admitdate)
where visitYear='2010'
```

Comment: If it's a date - you should **store it** as a `Date` (or `DateTime`) - then you could easily do this, without all the conversion and formatting hassle....

Comment: But why is `VisitYear` a `varchar` ?? You could easily make it a **computed column** with a formula of `YEAR(admitdate)` and be done with it - SQL Server would automagically keep the year (as an INT) in there for you....

Comment: visitYear is varchar because there are some people who are in a 2010 data set that were actually admitted in 2009 because their length of stay spanned a year.  So someone who was admitted in late 2009 could be in the 2010 dataset year.

Comment: It was just the easiest thing for me to do at the time.  I'm still chugging along learning how to use SSMS and SQL Server and not wanting to drop anything from the database until I'm comfortable with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 all queries are part of a transaction that is implicitly committed.  I'm assuming you are okay with using the dateadd function, what you have looks correct.  So to modify to allow rollback you could do the following - although not sure when / why you would rollback, that logic would need to be added.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION addDateYears
update myTable
set admitdate=dateadd(yyyy,10,admitdate)
where visitYear='2010'

/* IF SOMETHING ROLLBACK TRANSACTION addDateYears */

COMMIT TRANSACTION addDateYears
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it on your table:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE dbo.myTable
SET admitdate = DATEADD(YEAR, 10, admitdate)
WHERE visitYear = '2010'

SELECT visityear, admitdate 
FROM dbo.myTable
WHERE visitYear = '2010'

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Of course - if you want to actually apply the update, use `COMMIT` instead of `ROLLBACK` ....

Comment: The data are from 2011.  I need to add 10 years to the field admitdate, which happened in 2010.  Many of them erroneously have the year 2000 stored.